# Getting 'invalid drawable'

Tags: java, macos, opengl, jna

I'm trying to use OpenGL directly from Java using JNA on Mac OSX (I have done it successfully with Windows and Linux).  I've browsed thru JOGL source but they use CALayers which I don't understand yet.  I would like to just simply use NSOpenGLView if possible and place it over top the AWT Canvas.  I find the NSWindow using JNA and add the NSOpenGLView I created and it seems to work except when I call [nsOpenGLContext setView] or [nsOpenGLView lockFocus] I get an 'invalid drawable' error.  I learned from Rococoa how to use ObjectiveC from Java.

Here is some sample code:

```
  private static boolean createMac(GL gl, Component c) {
    NSAutoreleasePool pool = new NSAutoreleasePool();
    pool.alloc();
    pool.init();
    gl.nsopenglview = new NSOpenGLView();
    gl.nsopenglview.alloc();
    Pointer ptr = Native.getWindowPointer(findWindow(c));
    NSObject nsComponent = new NSObject();
    nsComponent.obj = ptr;
    Pointer cClass = nsComponent._class();
    NSView view = new NSView();
    view.alloc();
    boolean isView = view.isKindOfClass(cClass);
//    JFLog.log("test=" + isView);
    if (isView) {
      view.dealloc();
      view.obj = ptr;  //do NOT dealloc this (usually NSWindowViewAWT)
      gl.nswindow = view.window();
    } else {
      view.dealloc();
      gl.nswindow = new NSWindow();
      gl.nswindow.obj = ptr;
    }
    NSOpenGLPixelFormat fmt = new NSOpenGLPixelFormat();
    fmt.alloc();
    fmt.initWithAttributes(new int[] {
      NSOpenGLPFAWindow,
//      NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,  //is not available on my test system
      NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
      NSOpenGLPFAColorSize,24,
      NSOpenGLPFADepthSize,16,
        0  //zero terminate list
      }
    );
    if (fmt.obj == null) {
      JFLog.log("NSOpenGLPixelFormat initWithAttributes failed");
      return false;
    }
    if (gl.nsopenglview != null) {
      gl.nsopenglview.initWithFrame(new NSRect(c.getBounds()), fmt);
    }

    NSView content = gl.nswindow.contentView();
    JFLog.log("content view=" + content.obj);
    content.addSubview(gl.nsopenglview);
    JFLog.log("layered=" + content.wantsLayer());

    //use created context
    gl.nsopenglcontext = gl.nsopenglview.openGLContext();

    //create some resize/move listeners
    final GL _gl = gl;
    final Component _c = c;
    c.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        _gl.nsopenglview.setFrame(new NSRect(_c.getBounds()));
      }
      public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        _gl.nsopenglview.setFrame(new NSRect(_c.getBounds()));
      }
      public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}
      public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
    });
    if (api == null) {
      api = new GLFuncs();
      gl.glLibrary = NativeLibrary.getInstance("OpenGL");
      try {
        Field fields[] = api.getClass().getFields();
        for(int a=0;a<fields.length;a++) {
          String name = fields[a].getName();
          try {
            fields[a].set(api, gl.glLibrary.getFunction(name));
          } catch (Throwable t) {
            JFLog.log("OpenGL:Warning:Function not found:" + name);
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        JFLog.log(e);
      }
    }
    pool.release();
    return true;
  }
```

I can't use the drawRect function in NSOpenGLView so I just lockFocus, use gl commands and unlockFocus when done.  But the NSOpenGLContext doesn't have a view assigned and trying to assign the one I created generates the 'invalid drawable'.

Any ideas?

If you want a full working demo goto http://javaforce.sf.net and download v7.15.0, run ant in /jf and then in /projects/jtest3d and then execute run.sh (click the GLCanvas test).

Comment: More recent OSX Java releases (from 1.7 on) have deprecated the usage of JAWT to obtain handles to native windows.  Presumably at some point the behavior of `Native.getWindowPointer()` will become undefined on OSX.

Comment: I've made some progress, I use NSOpenGLLayer now and I don't get the 'invalid drawable' anymore.  But the layer remains invisible.  I think I need to override updateLayer() which is not easy to do from JNA.  But drawing from a callback will not work with my libraries design.  And then there is technomage comment that JAWT is deprecated (even though JOGL still uses it).

Comment: I think I know the problem.  I've tried to use other Cocoa functions like NSWindow and nothing appears.  I think you can't use Mac GUI functions off the main thread.  How would I call Cocoa from the main thread?

Comment: I can use other methods to get the handle to the window other than JAWT if that no longer works (enumerate WindowList)

Comment: [rococoa](https://code.google.com/p/rococoa/source/diff?spec=svn209&r=209&format=side&path=/trunk/rococoa/rococoa-core/src/main/java/org/rococoa/internal/MainThreadUtils.java) has some utilities for invoking a callable on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!  The problem was in Rococoa (or possibly a bug in JNA).  Their NSRect structure does not pass to [NSOpenGLView initWithFrame] or [NSWindow initWithContentRect] properly.  If I pass the 4 fields directly (x,y,width,height) to the function instead of the Structure itself then it works.  Also I used [NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread] to make sure I do all GUI stuff on the main thread.

So it is possible to use OpenGL using pure JNA from Java.  No native code needed.
This should be available in my javaforce.sf.net in v7.16 which I'll release in a while.

Thanks.